# Proper handling SQLite Database Corruption in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I saw [DatabaseErrorHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseErrorHandler.html) interface that have [onCorruption](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseErrorHandler.html#onCorruption%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method , this interface can be passed to the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor . my question is what is a good implementation to provide in this method ? should i handle the delete side-effect problems only ?? or what causes this method to be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is nothing special you want to do when the database gets corrupted then pass in `null`. The [DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.html) will be used then. It deletes the database since corruption can't be repaired in SQLite afaik. Luckily it should never happen - SQLite is pretty robust.